# Fix Height for a TabControl in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `User Control` with height `Height="500"` that Will have a TabControl with some items, I want to assign ***320*** to be the `height of TabControl`, However I am using others UserControls as Content for TabControl, those controls have height assigned as `DesignHeight="320"`

```
<UserControl x:Class="GUI.ProcessManager"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUI"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="705" Height="500">
        <Grid>
            <TabControl Margin="0">
                <TabItem  Header="Tab 1">
                    <local:otherUserControl />
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem  Header="Tab 2">
                    <local:otherUserControl2 />
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>

        <telerik:RadButton Content="Ok" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,450,0,0" Name="BtnOk" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" Click="BtnOk_Click" />
         <telerik:RadButton Content="Cancel" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="545,450,0,0" Name="BtnCancel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Click="BtnCancel_Click"/>
    </Grid >
</UserControl>
```

I want to give the TabControl a size of `320` and after that I want to put Ok and Cancel buttons, so they wont change position when user selects tabs

To do so I added a grid row definition

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="320"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And assigned row 0 to TabControl:

```
 <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Margin="0">
  ...
  </TabControl>
```

Then assigned row 1 to Buttons:

```
<telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="1" Content="Ok" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,450,0,0" Name="BtnOk" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" Click="BtnOk_Click" />
```

But I am only getting the window with The tab and then a blank space but without buttons are dissappering, Why is this happening or what am I missing

How to fix the size of TabControl so I can put buttons after that fixed size?

Comment: Oh! I thought I put "c#" let me edit that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `DockPanel`:

```
<DockPanel>       
    <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0" Height="320">
        <TabItem  Header="Tab 1">
            <local:otherUserControl />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem  Header="Tab 2">
            <local:otherUserControl2 />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="2,5">
        <telerik:RadButton Content="Ok" Name="BtnOk" Click="BtnOk_Click" />
        <telerik:RadButton Content="Cancel" Name="BtnCancel" Click="BtnCancel_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

The whole example would also be possible with using a `Grid` but it is necessary to remove the `Margin` from the `Button`s.

Comment: This works, however How would I set position of buttons? using `Margin="25,450,0,0"` seems is not working

Comment: Set the `Margin="5"` so you have the `Margin` between the `Buttons` defined and use `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` for the `StackPanel`

Comment: what do you want exactly with the `Margin`? you don't need it

Comment: I thought you could use Margin

Comment: normally you want a design which depends on the size of the window so you don't set a `Margin` for absolut positioning only for some delta between the controls